# Codeception PhpBrowser grabAttributeFrom throws Exception DOMDocument::loadXML()

Tags: codeception

I updated my tests from Codeception 2.0.9 to 2.1.5.

Everything works fine except the `PhpBrowser::grabAttributeFrom()` method. I'll get a PHPUnit exception like this:

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity, line: 3
```

or

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 141 and a in Entity, line: 142
```

It seems, that the `grabAttributeFrom` is very strict with HTML-DOM parsing. I googled the message and found, that the `DOMDocument::loadHtml()` is a bit less strict and would work.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

How can I fix this grabAttributeFrom? I need the content of a `href/src` attribute of a HTML file.

Comment: Could you get the stacktrace? run this test with -vvv flag.

Comment: Is the REST module enabled in the same suite?

Comment: Oh. Yes, that seems the solution for this problem. REST Module and PhpBrowser doesn't work together anymore. :( 

I need the REST Bundle to check HTTP-Headers in this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint of @Naktibalda guides myself to the resolution. It's a conflict of the modules REST and PhpBrowser. Both modules have implemented the function `grabAttributeFrom`. To get the right one, you have to change the order in the configuration, to get the one of PhpBrowser:

```
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        url: 'http://www.domain.com'
    - PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://www.domain.com'
```

This works for me, because PhpBrowser now overrules the method in the builded AcceptanceTester.php.