# Can't get containts from xpath codeception

Tags: xpath, codeception

I have element

```html
<a href="/s-xQ6qeR/documents/download?revid=28">
          <span class="icon icon-file-pdf-o" style="vertical-align: middle"></span> test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf
</a>
```

I need to check this element on page
I try do it:

```
$fileHref = $this->I->grabAttributeFrom("//a[contains(., 'test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf')]", 'href');
```

But I got error:

> Step  Grab attribute from "//a[contains(.,
>   'test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf')]","href"  Fail  Element that matches CSS
>   or XPath element with '//a[contains(., 'test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf')]'
>   was not found.

Comment: The xpath seems to be OK. It's probably error in php code - maybe you reference wrong object, that does not contain such element.

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154931/codeception-phpbrowser-grabattributefrom-throws-exception-domdocumentloadxml

Answer (score 0):

I finded two way to check the text inside an html tag :

**1. Using the method `grabAttributeFrom` and then compare the result**

```php
$fileName = $I->grabTextFrom('//a[@href="/s-xQ6qeR/documents/download?revid=28"]/span');
$I->assertEquals('test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf', $fileName);
```

This can be usefull if you want to put the result inside a variable and use it for other tests later.

**2. Using method `seeElement` with the text to compare inside your xpath**

```php
$I->seeElement('//span[text()="test_upload_uwfacjtn.pdf"]');
```